# How long can I go without exhaustion on 10 days' rations?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, food-and-drink

The rules for exhaustion from starvation are given in the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Food) (and PHB) as:

> A character needs one pound of food per day and can make food last
>   longer by subsisting on half rations. Eating half a pound of food in a
>   day counts as half a day without food.
>
> A character can go without food for a number of days equal to 3 + his
>   or her Constitution modifier (minimum 1). At the end of each day
>   beyond that limit, a character automatically suffers one level of
>   exhaustion. A normal day of eating resets the count of days without
>   food to zero.

The second paragraph strikes me as odd, because it seems to imply that a creature with a reasonable Constitution modifier can make their rations last longer by alternately starving themselves for several days and then eating a full day's rations.<sup>1</sup> Perhaps there are more elaborate strategies that might last even longer.

So, given the above rules and assuming I have a Constitution modifier of +0, **what is the longest I can go on 10 days' rations without taking a level of exhaustion from lack of food, and what is the rationing strategy to achieve this?** Assume that I have no other food source besides these rations, but my other needs (e.g. thirst) are taken care of, so making these rations last is my only concern.

---

<sup>1</sup> On the other hand, maybe this isn't so odd, given that in real life, humans are evolved for survival in conditions of alternating feast and famine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 43 days

Assuming your logic is correct which it certainly seems to be by RAW. (And is discussed in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45756/does-a-character-with-10-constitution-only-need-to-eat-every-4-days))

#### Starve and Feast

The optimal rationing strategy would be to starve yourself for 3 days and then eat a full ration, resetting your count to zero. This is a cycle of 4 days. Multiply by 10 rations is 40 days and you have a *days without food count* of 0. Meaning you can survive 3 more days. At the end of the 44th day you will suffer exhaustion without additional food.

#### Half Rations

Any day you use half rations simply reduces the number of times you can reset your count by eating a full ration. Effectively costing you 3 days and only gaining 1/2 a day.

Comment: Ok, this seems to show that the starve and feast strategy is in fact the optimal one, which makes my question a duplicate.